# ¿Cómo resolver "Using unique option prefix 'database' is error-prone" y "ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value nombre_BD"

Tags: mysql, shell-script, mysqldump

Estoy haciendo una copia de mi base de datos desde un script en shell.

La copia se hace correctamente, pero al ejecutar el comando tengo estos mensajes:

```
 Dumping nombre_BD ... 
 Info: Using unique option prefix 'database' is
 error-prone and can break in the future. 
 Please use the full name 'databases' instead. 

 Warning: /usr/bin/mysqldump: ignoring option 
 '--databases' due to invalid value 'nombre_BD' 

 total 200108

-rw-r--r-- 1  ... 40979271 may 24 04:48 nombre_BD.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1  ... 40979272 may 24 04:38 nombre_BD.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1  ... 40961541 mar 17 04:44 nombre_BD.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1  ... 40985191 mar 15 18:17 nombre_BD.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1  ... 40979271 may 24 04:54 nombre_BD.gz

MySQL Dump is complete!
```

Esta es el script encargado de hacer el dump:

```
#!usr/bin/miCarpeta/miScript.sh
# List of databases to be backed up separated by space

dblist="nombre_BD"

# Directory for backups
backupdir=/miRutaParaElBackup

# Number of versions to keep
numversions=4

# Full path for MySQL hotcopy command
# Please put credentials into /root/.my.cnf
hotcopycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=~/.miRutaMuySegura/.mysql.cnf --lock-tables --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --events --routines --triggers --ignore-table=unaTablaAIgnorar --ignore-table=otraTablaAIgnorar --ignore-table=ignorarTambienEstaTabla"

# Create directory if needed
mkdir -p "$backupdir"
if [ ! -d "$backupdir" ]; then
   echo "Invalid directory: $backupdir"
   exit 1
fi

# Hotcopy begins here
echo "Dumping MySQL Databases..."
RC=0
for database in $dblist; do
   echo
   echo "Dumping $database ..."
   mv "$backupdir/$database.gz" "$backupdir/$database.0.gz" 2> /dev/null
   $hotcopycmd $database | gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz"

   RC=$?
   if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
     continue;
   fi

   # Rollover the backup directories
   rm -fr "$backupdir/$database.$numversions.gz" 2> /dev/null
   i=$numversions
   while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
     mv "$backupdir/$database.`expr $i - 1`.gz" "$backupdir/$database.$i.gz" 2> /dev/null
     i=`expr $i - 1`
   done
done

if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "MySQL Dump failed!"
   exit $RC
else
   # Hotcopy is complete. List the backup versions!
   ls -l "$backupdir"
   echo "MySQL Dump is complete!"
fi
exit 0
```

Como ven, para conectar a la base de datos estoy usando un archivo `.cnf`: **`file=~/.miRutaMuySegura/.mysql.cnf`** el cual está así:

```
[client]
    host      = localhost
    user      = miUsuario
    password  = "MiSuperSuperSeguraPassword"
    databases = nombre_BD

[mysql]
    default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
    databases = true

[mysqld]
    wait_timeout=300
```

Según leí en algunas respuestas sobre problemas similares, los errores serían porque MySQL no estaría reconociendo los nombres de bases de datos pasados en parámetros desde el script y que había que agregar  `[mysqldump] databases = true` cosa que he hecho, pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Según entiendo la opción `--databases` se utiliza solo cuando necesitas exportar 2 o mas bases de datos. Proba sacar esa configuración en `[client]` del archivo `.cnf` y concatenar el nombre de la base a tu variable `hotcopycmd`

Comment: Me parece tenes un error. Para concatenar 2 variables deberías hacer `"$hotcopycmd $database"` y diría que por esto te aparece el mensaje `Info`